# How to query the depth of the OpenGL stencil buffer

Tags: opengl, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-3

I have a function that has a minimum requirement for the bit depth of the OpenGL stencil buffer. I want that function to return an error if the current stencil buffer does not meet that requirement (or if there is no stencil buffer). Since GL_STENCIL_BITS is deprecated, what is the correct way to query for the bit depth of the stencil buffer?

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL ES 2.0 still has `GL_STENCIL_BITS`. So this should work for the default framebuffer:

```
GLint stencilBits = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_STENCIL_BITS, &stencilBits);
```

For FBOs, you should generally know if you have a stencil buffer, and how deep it is, since you created it. But if you need to query it:

```
GLint bufId = 0;
glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
    GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_NAME, &bufId);
GLint stencilSize = 0;
if (bufId != 0) {
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, bufId);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER,
        GL_RENDERBUFFER_STENCIL_SIZE, &stencilSize);
}
```

For the OpenGL Core Profile, this is the new way of getting the bit count of the stencil buffer for the default framebuffer:

```
GLint stencilSize = 0;
glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,
    GL_STENCIL, GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_STENCIL_SIZE, &stencilSize);
```

and for a currently bound FBO:

```
GLint stencilSize = 0;
glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,
    GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_STENCIL_SIZE, &stencilSize);
```

For ES 3.0, it looks like both of these options are supported, based on the spec.

Things get a little more complicated for FBOs with combined depth/stencil attachments. If you need that, consult the spec documents for the exact behavior.

Comment: Thank you. Does glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_STENCIL,GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_STENCIL_SIZE,&stencilSize) work regardless of configuration? I read in the documentation that parameters differ depending on whether FBO is used or not.

Comment: I added some more cases for FBOs.

Comment: I searched the 3.2 core specification for `FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_STENCIL_SIZE` and did not find it, so you must mean some later version of Core Profile.